# Implement facebook sign up without https on production angular app

Tags: angular, facebook

I have implement facebook sign up into angular app but when I am running app on production then I am getting below error.

```
Until <app-name> updates its security settings, you won't be able to use Facebook to log in to it.
```

Any help?

Comment: It is not possible. You have to use https.

Comment: @WizKid Okay
thanks for the update.